# Joomla sigplus Plugin: Add new parameter

Tags: php, popup, gallery, joomla2.5

I'm working on a joomla 2.5 website and I'm using the [SIGPlus plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/content-photo-gallery/11426) to display an image gallery. The gallery is displayed using the boxplus popup engine.

Most of the functionality is there out of the box but I want to add a new parameter, that defines the color of a 'topbar'. The topbar is a css property on the boxplus-viewer element and looks something like this:

```
.boxplus-viewer {
  ...
  border-top: 10px solid <color>;
}
```

I'm trying to change the plugin syntax so that it takes an additional parameter 'topbar':

```
{gallery topbar=0099cc rows=15}joomlart/stories{/gallery}
```

so that the resulting css will look like this:

```
.boxplus-viewer {
  ...
  border-top: 10px solid #0099cc;
}
```

My problem is that I don't even see the 'topbar' property as part of the $curparams array. I've added the topbar property to the sigplus.xml but it still gets removed. How can I add it to the list of accepted params?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the parameter sigplus.xml is only helpful if you are going to only use what is entered in the plugin parameters to set the color of the top bar. If you want to add it as part of the plugin call, then you will need to edit sigplus.php (guessing on the file name, I have not looked at the plugin code). Somewhere in there you will find a regular expression that parses all of the parameters that are being passed in the plugin trigger. You will need to add to that so that the value entered is included in the $curparams array.

Comment: i think the regex you mention is in params.php or core.php. From what i can tell, it should take any key/value pair. just can't get it to accept a new parameter name yet... I understand that this is a very sigplus-specific question.